# 500 error Sending JSON to Controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6, model-binding

I am trying to send JSON data to the controller and use the data to modify the database.

This is my ajax call:

```
    var ajaxresult = [];
    var table = $('<table>').addClass('table ');
    $('button').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:' + $(this).attr('id') + '&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10',
        success: function (data) {

        ajaxresult.push(data);
        debugger;

        table.empty();
        table.append("<thead><tr><th>Avatar</th><th>Name</th><th>Score</th><th>URL</th><th>Updated at</th></tr></thead>");
        $.each(data.items, function (i, object) {

            var row = $('<tr>').addClass('table-primary');
            row.append('<td><img src=' + object.owner.avatar_url + 'height=50px width=50px/></td>');
            row.append('<td>' + object.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.score + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.url + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.updated_at + '</td>');
            table.append(row);

        });
        table.append('</table>');
        $('table').replaceWith(table);
    }

   });

  });

$('#save').on('click', function () {
debugger;
$.ajax({

    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:60294/Git/Updateto',
    data: ajaxresult,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('done');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('error');
    }
});

});
```

This is the controller to which I am trying to POST the data:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Updateto(List<gitd> obj,gitd gitd )

    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                item.AvatarURL = gitd.AvatarURL;
                item.Name = gitd.Name;
                item.Score = gitd.Score;
                item.Updatedat = gitd.Updatedat;
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return View(gitd);

    }

}
```

This is the model which I want to use and save data to the database:

```
public class gitd
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AvatarURL { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Score { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updatedat { get; set; }

    }
```

I am getting a 500 Internal error, when I looked using the debugger, whenever the POST request is called. the control moves directly to the close of the ajax function. In the JQUERY XML, I could see that **data is undefined** and **handleobj is undefined** and all the post data becomes NULL.How do I resolve this?
As ajaxresult is a global variable,shoudl not the json data be there in the #save button ajax call?Why is the data NULL.

I also tried giving data inside the POST request as:

```
 data:{
        "name":"John",
        "age":30,
        "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
       }
```

but still the error persists.

Comment: You don't seem to be posting anything to `/Git/Updateto`. Are you missing the `data` property of the object passed onto `$.ajax`?

Comment: I thought the data I am getting from the GET request will by default remain.New to ajax and Jquery. How do I POST the data I have received through the GET request?

Comment: I tried the following code, but still the 500 error occurs:`var jsonData = {
    "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe", "DoB": "01/01/1970",
};

$('#save').on('click', function () {
   
    $.ajax({
       
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonData,
        url: 'http://localhost:60294/Git/Updateto',        
        
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});`

Comment: Use F12 tools in the browser to work out what the browser is or isn't posting to the controller. Use a breakpoint in your code to see what the 500 error is caused by. A 500 error is thrown by your server side code but it can be from bad data posted to it.

Comment: Hi, I tried debugging it, the post does not throw an error for the default action, however it is throwing the 500 error if the action is Updateto. I have included the Updateto action in the controller, but still i get a error saying Updateto page cannot be found. Why is this so?`[HttpPost]
        public void Updateto(List<gitd> obj,gitd Git)
        {
            //Perform operations on obj
               
        }` This action is present in the controller but still why do I get the error?

Comment: Also when I navigate to the this URL- Git/Updateto - I get the page not found error, is this because the URL is under[HttpPost]?